# How to force my span to have a defined height?

Tags: html, css

I want to display "cards" in a line (for ex. 4 cards on each line). Each card is a `div` that contains a title (a `span`). My main problem is that the height of the title will change regarding the number of lines required to display the whole title.

So if I have a title that needs 2 lines to be displayed, the cards that contains itself will be shifted compared to the ones where the title can be displayed in only one line.

In such case, I get something like that:

```
         +-----+
+-----+  | ABC |  +-----+
| ABC |  | DEF |  | ABC |  
+-----+  +-----+  +-----+
|     |  |     |  |     |
|     |  +-----+  |     |
+-----+           +-----+
```

Here is a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eO9MwDyhFQg3BriMjikJ?p=preview

How can I solve that, i.e. I want all the cards to have the same height, and of course perfectly aligned.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this question is a duplicate, but I was not sure of what to search for exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align` on the class title for spans:

```
 .title {
   vertical-align:top;
 }
```

For default is `baseline` that makes the span align change based on the lenght of another baseline text `inline-block` elements.

<sub>You can also add this to the `xxx` class and works</sub>

Check this Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/X8vmBasqq3lZslMylSjI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. My code is slightly different, but I think your solution will solve my issue. I will check tomorrow if everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?
i have replaced display inline block with float left
http://plnkr.co/edit/xvP2ElSyEV1oXHSkV4Fb?p=preview